# Add a prefix in all css selectors of imported css

Tags: css, reactjs

In my React app (created with create-react-app):

***index.js***

```
...
import "@mock/style/css/mock.css";
```

`I want to add a prefix in all css selectors included in the above file`. What is the best way to achieve that? Should I use a package like `postcss-prefix-selector` or `Autoprefixer`? Should I change `Webpack` configuration? Not sure about the best approach to follow and not sure how to do that...

Comment: I think postcss-prefix-selector is a good solution, there is even an example of how to use it in webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-prefix-selector#usage-with-webpack

Comment: No Autoprefixer doesn't achieve what you want. Do you want to add a prefix in front of all the classes only? For instance `.test` would become `.abc-test`. This is exactly what you want? (If yes this might break your website since in some JS files we may find references to CSS classes)

Comment: Can you please detail more your request?

Comment: .test should become #myapp  .test

Comment: I see so you want to increase the specificity of all the selectors

Answer (score 1):

PostCss with [postcss-prefix-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-prefix-selector) is a good choice for your case, and yes, you should change your webpack config. But it is quite simple too, [here it is.](https://github.com/RadValentin/postcss-prefix-selector#usage-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use css modules. This means that you change the file extension of a .css file to .module.css. Then you can import and use it like this:

```
import styles from '@mock/style/css/mock.module.css';

<p className={styles.redText}>Hello this text is red</p>
```

The css module file would look something like this:

```
.redText{
  color:red;
}
```

You can name the styles import however you want. In a module css file all the rules have to be for classes or id's you can't use it to style all p elements for example.
For more information you can look at the documentation from react: [css modules react](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).